# Synchronous `multi_get` is way faster than asynchronous `get`. Does this make sense?

Tags: python, couchbase

I am noticing that performing a synchronous `multi_get` is way faster from an asynchronous `get` performed with `asyncio.gather`. We are talking P99 latency of 40 vs. 100 ms. Does this make sense?

Here is my code

```
async def main_async(cls, keys):
        cb = await cls.get_cb_conn_async()
        tasks = []
        for k in keys:
            task = asyncio.create_task(cls.cache_get_async(cb, k))
            tasks.append(task)
        
        res = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

        return res

async def cache_get_async(cls, cb, key):
        val_dict = {}
        does_exist = await cb.exists(key)
        if does_exist.exists:
            x = await cb.get(key)
            val_dict = x.value
        return {key: val_dict}

def main(cls, keys):
        cb = cls.get_cb_conn()
        return cls.pipe_get(cb, keys)

def pipe_get(cls, cb, keys):  
        n_results = len(keys)
        val_dicts = [{}] * n_results
        results = cb.get_multi(keys, quiet=True).results
        for k in keys:
            if results.get(k):
                val_dicts[keys.index(k)] = {k: cls.cache_to_dict(results.get(k).value)}
            else:
                val_dicts[keys.index(k)] = {k: {}}
        return val_dicts
```

I run `main_async` for async calls and `main` for sync calls.

I tried running the code I mentioned above.

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: The code is in Python